# how to solve exit status 1 error?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, compiler-errors, exitstatus

I want to write c++ code which will separate all elements which have same length as input value

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
string database[] = {"green", "stupid", "boy", "girl", "forest", "mobile", "morning", "love", "keyboard", "incredible"};
string input;
string count(string input, string database[]){
    string lengthFilter[] = {};
    int inputLength = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < database->length(); ++i){
        if (database[i].length() == inputLength)
        {
            lengthFilter[lengthFilter->length()] = database[i];

        }
    }
    return (lengthFilter);
}

int main()
{
    cin >> input;
    cout << count(input, database);
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives error

```
main.cpp: In function 'std::__cxx11::string count(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string*)':
main.cpp:16:22: error: could not convert 'lengthFilter' from 'std::__cxx11::string [0] {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> [0]}' to 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
  return (lengthFilter);
                      ^

exit status 1
```

I can't find my mistake, please, help me.

Comment: What character of the compiler error messages doesn't you understand?

Comment: lengthFilter is an array of strings, you need to return a string or change the signature of your count function.

Comment: The title of your question is quite misleading. `exit status 1` will appear on **any error** detected by the compiler. Also why are you using raw arrays of `std::string`? Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stepped into the shortcomings of built-in C++ arrays and the `[]` syntax. This:

```
[]
```

Does not always mean what you think it means. Its meaning varies by context. In declarations:

```
string database[] = // ...
```

It means you're declaring a built-in array. However, in function arguments:

```
string count(string input, string database[])
```

it's a pointer. The above line is equivalent to:

```
string count(string input, string* database)
```

Also note that this:

```
string lengthFilter[] = {};
```

Declares a built-in array of zero size. I don't think this is what you want, since built-in arrays are fixed size. They don't resize.

So what you should be doing here, is use `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> database = {
    "green", "stupid", "boy", "girl", "forest", "mobile", "morning", "love",
     "keyboard", "incredible"
};

string input;

vector<string> count(string input, const vector<string>& database)
{
    vector<string> lengthFilter;
    auto inputLength = input.length();
    for (const auto& i : database) {
        if (i.length() == inputLength) {
            lengthFilter.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return lengthFilter;
}

int main()
{
    cin >> input;
    for (const auto& i : count(input, database)) {
        cout << i << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```